# time limit exceed in the code that sums the numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

in the question there will be a number taken from user. Up to that number, I want to find the sum of all numbers if the sum of that number's digits is odd.
For example if the input is 13 then ;
1+3+5+7+9+10+12 = 47 should be the result.
In order to prevent time limit exceed, question says "Since the answer might be too big, please print the answer in modulo 10^9+7"

Constraints
1 ≤ n < 10^17  (n is input)

Here is my code:

```
MOD = 1000000007
def getSum(number):
    total = 0
    while number > 0:
        total += number % 10
        number //= 10
    return (total % MOD) % 2

def sticker(number):
    stickerNeed = 0
    for oneDigit in range(1, number):
        if (getSum(oneDigit % MOD) == 1):
            stickerNeed += oneDigit
    return stickerNeed % MOD


number = int(input())
result = sticker(number)
print(result % MOD)
```

But it still cannot handle the really big numbers and gives time limit exceed. Can you help me out? What wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this from Project Euler?

Comment: no, it is from an algorithm contest in my school club.

Comment: every time the problem description talks about really big numbers there is an algebraic solution to the problem. Just brute forcing will take a long long time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely, brute force is not right way for given range.

Instead think about the next:

```
1 3 5 7 9 10 12...18 21...29 30...98 100 102..108 111...199 201...999 1000 1002...
```

We can see that ever decade `*0..*9` contains exactly 5 numbers with odd digit sum, but these numbers can start from `*0` or from `*1`.

Aslo note that every hundred `*0..*99` contains five decades starting from `0`, and five decades starting from `1`

Let's separate the end of series after last `*00` value for simplicity and calculate their sum using function like your `sticker` but with corrected mistakes (your function gives wrong results).

Right function (not the fastest, but suitable for our purposes):

```
def sumofOdds(a, b):
    result = 0
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        t = i
        s = 0
        while t:
            s += t%10
            t //= 10
        if s%2:
            result += i
    return result
```

For example, for input `231`, calculate sum for range `200..231` as described above, and for `1..199` as described below

But what about swarm of numbers before last `*00`?

Sum of these numbers is sum of **arithmetic progression** of the sequence `0,2,4,...*98` plus addition of `25 * number of hundreds` (because every hundred contains `5` decades starting from `1` and they give `25` additional units). Note - this is one-liner formula.

Where to use `MOD`? In formula for arithmetic progression sum, after summation with `25 * number of hundreds`, and after summation with "end of series" sum.  But not in `getSum` and `sticker`

I hope these ideas will be useful for your solution

Test result:

```
46781934    #input
321669645   #by formula, calculated in microseconds
321669645   #by brute force, calculated in one minute
```

P.S. For range 10^17 we have to use modular aritmetics inside `sumofOdds` in languages without in-built support of big integers (Python works with such numbers well)

```
  if s%2:
     result = (result + i) % MOD
```